# React component not rendered every time on website

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I got a simple react component added to a web page and it is not rendering every time. It comes after I clear my browser history and then if I refresh my page it is not rendered. am I using old cdns or Babel?

This is my component and HTML.

React file find_new.js

```
'use strict';
class FindNew extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
      <li className="list-inline-item">
        <select className="selectpicker show-tick">
            <option>Newly published</option>
            <option>Recent</option>
            <option>Old Review</option>
        </select>
        </li>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#find_new');
ReactDOM.render(<FindNew/>, domContainer);
```

HTML

```
<div id="find_new"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="reactme/find_new.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not using CRA, just asking.

Comment: Are you using Chrome?  Have you tried disabling cache in developer mode and keeping the Chrome developer console open while testing changes?

Comment: Hello HoldOffHunger, that component works exactly after I clear Chrome history. and if I just refresh the page it is gone.

Comment: CRA stands for Create React App (https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html). It's Facebook's recommended way to create a new React app. If you've done significant development, it may not be worth migrating to use it.

Comment: This is Django project and I just wanted to add a couple of snippets